# SAS Running out of memory while calling macros

Tags: sas

When I need to call a macro several times, I've been using CALL EXECUTE in a DATA *NULL* step like so:

```
DATA _NULL_;
  DO i=1 to 1000;
  CALL EXECUTE ('%mymacro');
  RUN;
```

This has worked fine for me up until now. However if I use this method to call %mymacro a million times (say), I get an "out of memory" error before it runs the macro once.

My naive understanding of this is that SAS attempts to "write out" the macro a million times before executing and thus runs out of memory during this process. Is this accurate? And: what are good ways to get around this?

Comment: What happens if you switch `call execute` to `dosubl`?

Comment: How extensive is `%mymacro` ?   Calling a macro 1E6 times indicates an incomplete or poorly scaling design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to understand how `Call Execute` works :

Basically ,`Call Execute` will parse the macro code immediately, but it queues up the resulting SAS steps until after the current data step finishes. In other words, you are potentially building up millions upon millions of lines of SAS code in memory that SAS is just storing up to be executed when that `data _null_` step finishes. Eventually, this gets so large that SAS just crash.

Here's a couple of solutions :

> 1- Either add `%nrstr()` into your CALL EXECUTE statements.
>
> 2- Or change your `data _null_` step to generate a file with the code and `%include` the file.

Comment: Okay, yes: I was thinking that CALL EXECUTE "put aside" the current data step, executed whatever it was to execute, then went back to the original data step.

Comment: If you find my answer helpful, I hope you accept it ;)

Comment: How does calling %nrstr(%mymacro) help the issue? Does SAS queue up instances of just the string '%mymacro' (or whatever) instead?

Comment: `%NRSTR` function masks character string during compilation of the macro, `CALL EXECUTE ('%nrstr(%yourmacro);');` SAS won't write the source code of the macro each time but just the call for it.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to chage the data step so that it actually creates a `.sas` file that contains the macro calls... and then `%include` it.  For exmaple:

```
data _null_;
  file "myfile.sas";
  do i=1 to 1000;
    put '%mymacro';
  end;
run;

%include "myfile.sas";
```

This *may* fix the issue.  Then again I'm not sure if SAS would like a `.sas` program that contains 1 million lines of code either.  If the latter is the case, then simply break the program up into 10 `.sas` files each with 100k lines of code.